# Improving speed elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

i have setup 3 node clusters (24 core each).
when i run query that time it's giving slow result.
but i have created a stand alone server and ran same query that time giving fast result.

my cluster and data details:-
i have created 12 indexer and around 3 shards each.
total size of data 60gb.
elastic search version 5.3
server disk 500gb each.
so kindly guide me how to achieve better speed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add more detail, like server types, disk speeds, what type of data you are indexing.

Comment: Server disk 500gb each , I have using SQL data use.

Comment: Are the disk SSD ? Is this clustered hosted in AWS / Azure / Local ? for example.

Comment: What version of Elastic are you using ? Does it run X-pack?

Comment: I have using 5.3 ,I have not using x-pack

Comment: I have using aws servers

Comment: Update your question with as much details as possible. Ideally with what instance types you are using in AWS. How the instances are hosted i.e by regions/availability zones, if the disks are EBS backed for example. You should then have some luck with people pointing you in some directions.

Comment: There's no reduce required in a single node cluster.